# Как записать данные через Python в бд?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Возникла  проблема с записью данных.

Например, я хочу реализовать запись количество действий (для телеграм-бота).
По умолчанию для каждого пользователя значение равняется нулю, но я не знаю как прибавить к этому числу 1.

Гайды читал, как подключать бд знаю, нужен только алгоритм  счёта и записи в столбец для определенного id.

Использую библиотеку sqlite3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect('example.db') as con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('UPDATE yourtable SET n = n + 1 WHERE id = ?', (user_id,))
```

- Вместо example.db вставляете ваш файл с БД sqlite.
- Вместо yourtable название нужной таблицы
- В переменной user_id должен быть нужный id
- Вместо n название столбца, в котором хранится количество.

Comment: Выводит такую ошибку:

`UNIQUE constraint failed: data.user_id`

Все данные заполнил верно, что может быть не так?

Comment: @Anonim Похоже будто вы пытаетесь добавить ещё одну строку с тем же user_id в бд. Неплохо бы увидеть вашу таблицу, её содержимое и код, которым обновляете данные.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/r74R4U2t

Comment: @Anonim cur.execute('UPDATE nazar SET bow = bow + 1 WHERE id = ?', (user_id, bow))` - сюда bow передавать не нужно. Только (user_id, ) - обязательно с запятой. Но ошибка у тебя на другой запрос - на INSERT INTO nazar. Видимо пытаешься добавить юзера с тем же id, который уже есть в базе. А они должны быть уникальны.

Comment: Для user_id уникальность стоит, не NULL тоже.  

Сейчас убрал bow после user_id, теперь новая ошибка:

` NameError: name 'bow' is not defined`

Comment: Это не связано напрямую с тем, что из cur.execute убран bow. Это уже ошибка из самого питона. Где-то в коде обращаешься к переменной bow, а её нет в доступных областях видимости. В описании ошибки указана строка и файл, где она появляется.